# How to retrieve the key-value pairs from an OpenCV FileNode map?

Tags: c++, opencv, file-storage

I am storing a map in a yaml file with OpenCV FileStorage, something like this:

```c
cv::FileStorage fs("file.yaml.gz", cv::FileStorage::WRITE);
std::string somekey = ...;
double someval = ...;
fs << "mymap" << "{:" << somekey << someval << "}";
```

Now, I want to get the data back, but I do not know the keys of the map. I guess the code should be like this:

```c
cv::FileStorage fs("file.yaml.gz", cv::FileStorage::READ);
cv::FileNode fn = fs["mymap"];
// fn has type == cv::FileNode::MAP
// fn has size == 1 element (one pair)
// fn[0] returns also a MAP with 1 element
```

Is is possible to get all the pairs of that map without the keys? I have checked the `cv::FileNodeIterator`, but it does not seem to solve this problem. The C interface, `CvFileNode`, allows to retrieve the values but just after providing the key.

Comment: You should look at using `FileNodeIterator`. I'm not up for writing a full answer, but as you iterate over each `FileNode mapFn` in your `fn`, I expect `mapFn.isNamed()` to be `true`, and `mapFn.name()` to give the actual name. I haven't tried it though, but I'm pretty sure something along these lines should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @SchighSchagh, you were right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer thanks to @SchighSchagh.

It is necessary to iterate through the node with a `cv::FileNodeIterator` and cast it later to a `cv::FileNode`. The key is then stored as the name of this `cv::FileNode`:

```c
cv::FileStorage fs("file.yaml.gz", cv::FileStorage::READ);
cv::FileNode fn = fs["mymap"];

for(cv::FileNodeIterator fit = fn.begin(); fit != fn.end(); ++fit)
{
  cv::FileNode item = *fit;
  std::string somekey = item.name();
  double someval = (double)item;
  ...
}
```

It is important to realize that the notation `fit->name()` does not work with a `cv::FileNodeIterator`.

Comment: The arrow operator is actually supposed to work as expected, do you get any error when using it?

Comment: I obtain a compilation error when doing `fit->name()` with OpenCV 2.4.3: `error: result of ‘operator->()’ yields non-pointer result`.